# Castle Windsor's DictionaryAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, castle

I'm trying to upgrade one of our applications from Castle Windsor 2.1 to 2.5.

I've removed all of the Castle DLL's, and added the 2.5 version as downloaded from Castle's website:

Castle.Core.dll
Castle.Windsor.dll

Before doing the migration, I also had a reference on my project to:

Castle.Components.DictionaryAdapter.dll

However, according to Krzysztof Koźmic's post [here](http://kozmic.pl/2010/07/05/castle-windsor-2-5hellip-the-final-countdown-ndash-beta-1-released/), such reference is no longer necessary, since the DictionaryAdapter now comes bundled into Castle.Core.dll.

Upon removing it, I get errors all over the place saying:

> Error 6   The type or namespace name 'DictionaryComponent' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

and

> Error 64  The type or namespace name 'DictionaryKey' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> Error 27  The type or namespace name 'DictionaryKeyAttribute' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I then thought I'd add a reference to Castle.Components.DictionaryAdapter.dll, as it could be that CORE didn't have the types listed above implemented in it.

Doing that got rid of all the errors, but gave me a new one:

Error   8   The type 'Castle.Components.DictionaryAdapter.DictionaryAdapterFactory' exists in both 'd:.NET\app\libs\Castle.Core.dll' and 'd:.Net\app\libs\Castle.Components.DictionaryAdapter.dll'

The error happens on the following method implementation:

```
internal static ISettingService GetServiceFromAdapterFactory(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var adapter = new DictionaryAdapterFactory();
    return adapter.GetAdapter<ISettingService>(collection);
}
```

Has anyone faced such problem when upgrading from 2.1 to 2.5 and could offer me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question here, this is what I had to change in my code.

- Changed all the **DictionaryKey** to become **KeyAttribute**
- Changed all the **DictionaryComponent** to become **ComponentAttribute**
- Used **Kernel.Register** instead of **Kernel.AddComponent**

And obviously removed all the 2.1 DLL's and added the 2.5. You will notice that the DictionaryAdapter.dll has been removed, as it's now bundled within Castle.Core.dll

Hope that helps someone in the future.